# Azure APIM "rewrite-uri" policy - How to remove the URL suffix?

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a requirement where I have the Azure APIM public facing URL - https://api.example.com/api/v1/storenumber/ordernumber

And

Back-end service URL (**Notice** - There is no URL path suffix here) - https://back-end.service.com

So I need to remove "/api/v1/storenumber/ordernumber" in APIM.

How to achieve this in Azure APIM policies?

Thanks,
Aneesh.

Answer (score 16):

Let's say you have APIM service with hostname `my-service.azure-api.net`. An API in APIM service with URL suffix `my-api`, and a backend URI of `https://my-backend.com`. And an operation in this API with URI template of `my/uri/template`.

So for an incoming call to

https://my-service.azure-api.net/my-api/my/uri/template

without any additional configuration APIM service will make a call to

https://my-backend.com/my/uri/template

Because by default APIM service replaces in source URI scheme+hostname+api suffix with backend URI defined for an API in question.

In most simple case when your API has only one operation you could set API suffix to `api/v1/storenumber/ordernumber` and operation template to `/`. That would result in public facing URI of 
https://api.example.com/api/v1/storenumber/ordernumber

and backend URI for this operation of

https://back-end.service.com/

Of course this is approach is harder to use when you have multiple operations in API. In that case you'll need to use policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL. For that you can set your API suffix and operation URI template to anything, but add this policy into operation's inbound section:

```
<rewrite-uri template="/" />
```

what rewrite-uri policy does is overrides operation URI template for backend request.

Comment: Works, but leaves a single `/` at the end. Is there a way to remove that one as well?

Comment: I found a workaround for the issue with the `/`.  Simply replace this with a `?` not sure if there is a more elegant solution but this does the trick.