# Azure APIM Gateway is trimming the trailing slash in the api url

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a requirement to add trailing slash to the APIs hosted in APIM. However, APIM gateway seems to be removing the trailing slash when forward the call to backend service.

**Example 1**:

APIM Gateway URL: `https://api.domain.com/getdata/`

Backend service URL: `https://mybackendservice.domain.com/getdata`

**Example 2**:

APIM Gateway URL: `https://api.domain.com/getdata/?q=1&r=2`

Backend service URL: `https://mybackendservice.domain.com/getdata?q=1&r=2`

Can someone please suggest any URL rewrite policies we can add to retain the trailing slash, so that the backend service urls would be:

`https://mybackendservice.domain.com/getdata/`

`https://mybackendservice.domain.com/getdata/?q=1&r=2`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Vitaliy Kurokhtin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181556/vitaliy-kurokhtin) ,Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

"Let's say you have APIM service with hostname  `my-service.azure-api.net`. An API in APIM service with URL suffix  `my-api`, and a backend URI of  `https://my-backend.com`. And an operation in this API with URI template of  `my/uri/template`.

So for an incoming call to

```
https://my-service.azure-api.net/my-api/my/uri/template
```

without any additional configuration APIM service will make a call to

```
https://my-backend.com/my/uri/template
```

Because by default APIM service replaces in source URI scheme+hostname+api suffix with backend URI defined for an API in question.

In most simple case when your API has only one operation you could set API suffix to  `api/v1/storenumber/ordernumber`  and operation template to  `/`. That would result in public facing URI of  `https://api.example.com/api/v1/storenumber/ordernumber`

and backend URI for this operation of

```
https://back-end.service.com/
```

Of course this is approach is harder to use when you have multiple operations in API. In that case you'll need to use policies:  **[Rewrite URL |MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL)**  . For that you can set your API suffix and operation URI template to anything, but add this policy into operation's inbound section:

```
<rewrite-uri template="/" />
```

what rewrite-uri policy does is overrides operation URI template for backend request"

**Reference:**
[Azure APIM "rewrite-uri" policy - How to remove the URL suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314693/azure-apim-rewrite-uri-policy-how-to-remove-the-url-suffix)