# Wildcard requiring trailing slash in Azure API Management (APIM)

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In Azure API Management (APIM), I want to setup [wildcards for all GET and POST operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/add-api-manually#add-and-test-a-wildcard-operation) to my backend service. I'm encountering an issue where the consumer has to specify a trailing slash in order for the request to complete.

The wildcard is specified in APIM like this:

[image: Wildcard specified in APIM]

Example, these all work:

```
{{endpoint}}/devices/      <-- notice trailing slash here)
{{endpoint}}/devices/12345 
{{endpoint}}/devices/12345/foo
```

It's just the base endpoint of a resource that does not work without the trailing slash, like:

```
{{endpoint}}/devices
```

In my particular case, it doesn't seem to recognise the route without the explicit trailing slash and requires the user to authenticate.

Is there a way to accept both with/without trailing slashes?

Comment: Are these helpful? [WildCard option in azure apim for POST and GET REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/631841/wildcard-option-in-azure-apim-for-post-and-get-res.html) and [Azure APIM "rewrite-uri" policy - How to remove the URL suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314693/azure-apim-rewrite-uri-policy-how-to-remove-the-url-suffix)

Answer (score 0):

solved it as follow :

1. set up a `GET /{*path}` wildcard operation for current api
2. add the following policy to the operation inbound processing:
   `<rewrite-uri template="{path}" copy-unmatched-params="true" />`

[screenshots in github post](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1042#issuecomment-1367516493)